# Moving files across a computers connected by LAN

Tags: windows, linux, file, scripting, ftp

I am needed to move entire directories from one computer in the network to the other (In a platform independent way). Basically I am working on some automation tool to help the developers do Build Verification Tests, for this; I am directed to `automate` the installation and un-installation of  the product on multiple platforms. So, I will need to first copy the files!

And this is where I needed some help in both conceptual and practical knowledge.

Firstly, let me mention that using something like FileZilla or WinSCP is out of the question since I need things to happen `automatically` and not through button clicks. But please let me know if these tools have any command line utilities!

I tried Perl's NET::FTP, and while it looked promising, I was wondering whether it was the best way to go. Also, I want to know what are the pre-requisites before I can run FTP, I mean would I need perl installed on the other end as well ? I constantly read that the commands from perl's FTP actually try to connect to a `FTP host`, does this mean its not going to work if I haven't *configured* the remote host in some way? And if I am right, then what is this *extra* piece of configuration to be done?

Apart from this, is there any other way I could solve my problem ? I mean I am looking for API's here that would help me do platform independent file transfers. But once again, I cannot use tools that would need button clicks and stuff, because I am doing automation and everything needs be dome programmatic-ally and automatically.

Also, I think this is a very generic problem-statement: "Moving files across a computers connected by LAN"; So, it would be wonderful if we can have a list of (possibly) many options (ways to solve the problem) in the form of answers to this post.

Thanks in advance for any help that you wish to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nearly all of the files in your directory have changed, creating an archive, sending it over the network, and unarchiving makes sense. Actually, if your LAN is fast enough, though, it may be faster not to compress the archive--just use tar.

If only some of the files have changed, rsync, a command line tool, will only download the changes. It can be used with ssh like this:

rsync -ae ssh username@hostname:/path/to/files /store/here/locally

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/rsync-command-examples/

On Linux and OS X, cron and crontab allow you to schedule scripts to run periodically. Windows provides the Windows Task Scheduler.

FTP is fine if you don't care about encryption over your LAN. Otherwise, SSH would be preferable.

rsync is available on OS X and Linux, but I think you can use it on Windows through Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making an archive (e.g. a `.tar.gz` file) on the source host, transferring it with `scp`, and unarchive it on the target host.

You could also use [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) or `rsync`

Comment: to use scp, what packages wil I need to install ? Also, what would you say if I were to use perl to write the code, so that I have to run the same code for both platforms ..

Comment: `scp` is inside `ssh`; you may want the `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` package, and you need to read a tutorial about configuring and using it.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to develop your own FTP client in .NET.  This way you will have complete control over the application, and instead of button-clicks you can schedule it using windows-scheduler. Here is an article about how to create your own FTP client in VB.NET:

http://dot-net-talk.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-create-ftp-client-in-vbnet.html